# getting KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Scene Collection" not found' when I try and run this add on code

Tags: add-on

what does script is supposed to do is when you control left mouse button click a collection. It's supposed to select all the items in the collection and then you could do it again control left mouse button to select multiple collections... i'm getting the error that's in the title on Line 36 of this code. Any help on this would be appreciated...

NOTE: when you run it there is a button that has to be active in outliner filter settings For the script to function... and there's a bug in the script. I'm also trying to uncover that when you first install this add on or run it as a script in text editor you may have to disable and reenable that outliner filter button.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "My Collection Selector",
    "author": "me",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (3, 3, 1),
    "location": "Outliner > Filter > multi-select objects of collections > Active",
    "description": "Select collection and press ctrl + LMB in the same time",
    "category": "Collection",
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty,BoolProperty

class MSOCModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.msoc_modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "MSOC Modal Timer Operator"

    current: StringProperty()
    last: StringProperty()
    insert: StringProperty()
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.collection is not None #context.area.type  is 'OUTLINER' #and context.region.type == 'WINDOW'
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        
        self.current = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name
        
        #Get Correct Collection 
        if self.current != self.insert:
            self.insert = self.current
            if event.ctrl: 
                if bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name != 'Master Collection':     
                    for obj in bpy.data.collections[self.insert].all_objects:
                        isSelect = obj.select_get()
                        if isSelect == False:
                            obj.select_set(True)
                        else:
                            obj.select_set(False)
                    #print(bpy.data.collections[self.insert].name)
        
        #Lock to master collection
        bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
    
        #Cancel function
        if not context.scene.multi_select_collection:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
        self.last = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
       
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        #print("INVOKE")
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        self.last = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

#UI draw
def draw_msoc(self ,context):
    scene = context.scene
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text='multi-select objects of collections:') 
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(scene, "multi_select_collection",text="Active", toggle=False , icon = 'GROUP')
     
#Toggle update
def msc_status(self, context):
    if self.multi_select_collection:
        # call function
        bpy.ops.wm.msoc_modal_timer_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MSOCModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_PT_filter.append(draw_msoc)
    bpy.types.Scene.multi_select_collection = BoolProperty(update= msc_status)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MSOCModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_PT_filter.remove(draw_msoc)
    del bpy.types.Scene.multi_select_collection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of `bpy.context.scene.collection` and `bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection` has changed with Blender 3.0+ from 'Master Collection' to 'Scene Collection'.

```
print(bpy.context.scene.collection) 
print(bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection)

Blender < 3.0
<bpy_struct, Collection("Master Collection") at 0x000002AC35900A48>
<bpy_struct, LayerCollection("Master Collection") at 0x000002AC3599CF48>

Blender 3.0 >=
<bpy_struct, Collection("Scene Collection") at 0x0000010D2D52DC08>
<bpy_struct, LayerCollection("Scene Collection") at 0x0000010D2C5C27A8>
```

So change line 35 to `if bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name != 'Scene Collection':`

see: https://developer.blender.org/D11812